# Regexp to match a string even if white space(optional, due to user mistake) exist

Tags: c#, regex

I've to match pattern and i'm very bad in regexp.

I've to match a string like this `ABC-12345`, this one is perfect string.
But user can make mistake (as always for developers), user can add white spaces in patter in any side of hyphen
So, code should be able to match if it is

```
ABC- 12345      one white space left side of hyphen
ABC -12345      one white space right side of hyphen
ABC - 12345     one white space both side of hyphen
```

I've tried `/s`, `[[:blank:]]`, but they are making the white spaces mandatory, but i need it optional.

Comment: Use `*` after `\s`: `@"\s*"`

Comment: Why not just use `string.Replace(" ", "")` as input to your Regex?

Comment: there are other words before and after pattern, but yes, i'll try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a `*` after your whitespace character to match zero to many times:

```
string result = Regex.Match(input, @"[A-Z]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{5}").Value;
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YCvSct/1)

Alternatively, you can filter your string for whitespace before using Regex:

```
string result = Regex.Match(input.Replace(" ", ""), @"[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{5}").Value;
```